# store data into a path based on a field's value in the tuple

Tags: apache-pig

```
{'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}
....
```

Let's suppose above tupple gets loaded with following schema:

```
   as (firstField:chararray, secondField:chararray, thirdField:chararray)
```

I want to store the tuple in HDFS with the path based on 2nd field (which is 'bbb' in above example). So the above tuple would get stored in the path

```
 /SomeBaseDir/bbb/testoutput.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to elaborate your question... ? can you ?

Comment: Will the tuples have unique values for the second field? Can you post more than one tuple sample data?

Answer (score 0):

To load the file use below command. Remember the file input data should be tab separated.If you are using any other separator like comma then change the parameter passes in PigStorage funtion. It should be PigStorage(',')

```
A = load '/home/abhishek/Work/pigInput/data' using PigStorage('\t') as (firstField:chararray, secondField:chararray, thirdField:chararray);
```

Now, to get the second element simple use:

```
result = foreach A generate secondField;
```

Result

```
dump result
('bbb')
```

You can store it using below command

```
store result into 'provide the path';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use MultiStorage (https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html). This should do pretty much what you want. Specify base path, then the field on which subdirectories should be based.

Answer (score 0):

The SPLIT operator in PigLatin would do the job here.

For an input data (in) which is loaded, it could be split into different output variable as following:

```
loadedData = load ' ' as (.. ,somefield, ) using ... ;

SPLIT loadedData INTO
                       segmentA IF (somefield=='A'),
                       segmentB IF (somefield=='B'),
                       OtherSources OTHERWISE;

store segmentA into 'hdfs://<path for data segmentA >' using ....;
store segmentB into 'hdfs://<path for data segmentB >' using ....;
```